# Apache: VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

when i add the line below to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf I get the error belower when i restart apache:

```
Include
/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

> [Mon Jun 14 12:16:47 2010] [error]
>   VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and
>   non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost
>   address is not supported, proceeding
>   with undefined results [Mon Jun 14
>   12:16:47 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost
>   *:80 has no VirtualHosts

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName tirengarfio.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/rs3

   <Directory /var/www/rs3>
      AllowOverride All
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Allow from All
   </Directory>

   Alias /sf /var/www/rs3/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
   <Directory "/var/www/rs3/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi